# How to cache YouTube video metadata fetched through the API

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I've built a Video Gallery using the YouTube API (as a learning exercise), which I would like to make available on my site.

Basically, the gallery does an ajax call (via jQuery) to YouTube and uses the resulting JSON to build a gallery. But YouTube says thus:

> To avoid quota errors, high-traffic websites should cache video metadata fetched through the API for one to two hours..

So, now I know that I need to somehow cache the json response (I assume) or else every visitor to that page will be  calling the API.

In researching Stack, I've read everything from Memcached to localStorage, yet I'm not sure **which** to use.

So basically, I'd like to get ***a clue*** as to the **best way to proceed**. I'm  running wamp on win7/64, if this narrows my choices. Host is running linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is just one computer that is using the API, then you can cache the results in Local Storage in that local browser and check the cache before requesting data from the API.

If you're producing script that will be used in many, many browsers and you need caching that works across all those browsers, then you will need to cache the info on a server and either have the clients fetch the info from your server or just build the page server-side using the cached data.  You can't have one browser cache the info for another browser.

A cache on your server can either be done in memory or in a simple database depending upon the size of the data, resources on the server, difficulty in refetching the data if the server restarts, etc...

Comment: @friend00 Got it. Guess I will start looking into Memcached. That or it's back to MySQL.

Comment: Actually, I wound up just using a text file!